# json error message, can't see the SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this  JSON object from server

```
{status:"OK", response:"Thank you! .........."}
```

but on parsing the json i am getting this error message

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement.
```

I am getting the same error if i paste this json in FF console.

Comment: paste your code of parsing JSON and logcat

Comment: {"status":"OK", "response":"Thank you! .........."} - json validators say that this is the correct way of writing

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
{"status":"OK", "response":"Thank you! .........."}
```

Comment: Indeed. JSON keys need to be enclosed in double quotes. This is a reason why you should always let a library create your JSON, rather than doing it yourself.